# ¿Como formular la siguiente consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hola tengo una tabla que contiene una columna **gender** esta columna tiene las siguientes opciones asistio, no asistio, escusa

lo que pasa es que quiero hacer una consulta que me diga la numero que ***asistieron, no asistiero y con escusa*** hasta el momento tenia solo los que asitieron con la siguente consulta

```
 $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabledit WHERE gender = 'ASISTIO'");
    while($contador= mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
        $count=$contador[0];
    };
```

pero lo que quiero es eso conseguir tambien el numero de los que no asistieron o tienen escusa estaba, mirando en la base de datos y me sirvio la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT COUNT(gender)  AS Asistio FROM tabledit WHERE gender="asistio"; SELECT COUNT(gender) AS Excusa FROM tabledit WHERE gender="escusa" ; SELECT COUNT(gender) AS No_asistio FROM tabledit WHERE gender="No asistio";
```

pero me daba el siguiente resultado y creo que no es buena practica realizar estas consultas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y hay si no sabria como hacer para sacar el resultado por el php y asignarlo a una varible cada resultado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para eso deberías usar un "group by". Algo así:

```
SELECT gender, COUNT(*) AS Cantidad
FROM tabledit
GROUP BY gender
```

Eso te va a devolver todos los `gender` distintos y la cantidad de registros para cada uno de ellos.

Al margen de la consulta... ¿Por qué se llama "gender" la columna que dice si asistió o no? Es decir... "geneder" supongo que será por "género" en inglés...

Comment: funciona perfectamente, pero ahora como hago para que el codigo php me identifique cuantos asistieron , no asistieron y cuantos con excusa

Answer (score 1):

Con el siguiente código el resultado de query será la suma de cada uno de los grupos y con `echo` se mostrará en php los resultados de la consulta, el nombre del grupo y su cantidad.

```
$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT gender,COUNT(*) as cantidad FROM tabledit group by  gender");
    while($result= mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
        echo "Total ".$result[0]." ->".$result[1];
    };
```